# How to prevent sql injection/escape input in sqlite

Tags: scheme, sql-injection, guile

I'm using [guile-dbi](http://home.gna.org/guile-dbi/)/[sqlite](https://github.com/jkalbhenn/guile-dbd-sqlite3/) and I have code like this:

```
(dbi-query db-obj (string-append "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '"
                                 username
                                 "'"))
```

How can I escape username given from user to prevent sql injection?

I could validate username to only contain letters using `[a-zA-Z]` but what about other languages that have non latin letters and names like O'Conor?

Comment: This is a hard problem. Instead of accepting only Latin characters, you should exclude characters that have a special meaning for SQL, however. This might help: http://pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/sql-injection/mysql-sql-injection-cheat-sheet

Comment: @MichaelVehrs unfortunately there are no info about sqlite, that I'm using.

Comment: Sorry about that. The obvious culprits are `;`, `'` and `--`. There may be others. I suggest looking at one or more implementations of query builders.